# How repeat a same prerequisite in a Makefile target?

Tags: makefile

I want do something like this in a **Makefile** (with more tasks):

```
.PHONY: sep tasks task1 task2 task3

tasks: task1 sep task2 sep task3

task1:
    @echo task 1

task2:
    @echo task 2

task3:
    @echo task 3

sep:
    @echo
```

The result of the `tasks` target is:

```
task 1

task 2
task 3
```

The `sep` target is executed only the first time. That is perfectly normal. **But I want that executes each times. Is there a way to force repetition?**

A workaround is to use several `sep` targets like this:

```
tasks: task1 sep1 task2 sep2 task3
```

and with grouped targets definition all `sep` can be defined in one time:

```
sep1 sep2 &:
    @echo
```

The result with that is correct:

```
task 1

task 2

task 3
```

I want know if it is possible to have the same behavior with only one `sep` and force the repetition of this prerequisite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible.  There is no way to get make to build the same target more than one time per invocation of make.

Anyway, relying on this ordering is wrong: if you ever wanted to use parallel jobs (`make -j`) to allow your build to run faster, then this would not do what you wanted it to do.

The best thing to do is simply put the "sep" into the recipes for the targets:

```
task1:
        @echo
        @echo task 1
```

etc.